# My site doesn't look good in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

im working on a web app and my code is working good in chrome and explorer but on Firefox its giving me troubles.
i add a link to a screenshot so you can see how the menu looks(the black css boxes should be under the menu): 
[link to see the menu](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/593/menuprob.jpg/)

this is my style css :

/*-- Menu --*/

```
#menu { height:39px; position:relative; float:right; margin-top:33px; background:url(../images/menu/bg.jpg) repeat-x; }
#menu-left { width:8px; height:38px; position:relative; z-index:10; float:left; background:url(../images/menu/menu-sx.jpg); }
##menu-right { width:8px; height:38px; position:relative; z-index:10; float:right; background:url(../images/menu/menu-dx.jpg); }

.menu-item { float:left; position:relative; z-index:100; cursor:pointer; }
#menu-name { float:left; padding-top:10px; padding-right:11px; font-size:10pt; color:#FFF; text-shadow:#001F2E 0px -1px; }

#menu-rollover-left { width:98px; height:38px; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:0; background:url(../images/menu/rollover-left.jpg); }
#menu-rollover-right { width:86px; height:38px; position:absolute; top:0; right:0; z-index:0; background:url(../images/menu/rollover-right.jpg); }

/*-- Menu labels --*/
.label { height:34px; position:absolute; top:103px; z-index:200; opacity:0; filter:alpha(opacity=0); }
.label-left { width:9px; height:34px; float:left; background:url(../images/menu/label-left.jpg); }
.label-right { width:9px; height:34px; float:left; background:url(../images/menu/label-right.jpg); }
.label-center { height:34px; float:left; background:url(../images/menu/label-center.jpg) center; }
.label-center span { position:relative; top:7px; font-size:8pt; color:#FFF; text-shadow:#000 0px -1px; }

/*-- Notifications flag --*/
#header a { text-decoration:none;}
#red-flag { width:27px; height:51px; position:absolute; top:33px; right:62px; z-index:300; background:url(../images/menu/red-flag.png); font-size:9pt; color:#FFF; text-shadow:#3B0001 0px -1px; text-align:center; line-height:67px; cursor:pointer; }
```

and this is my html code :

```
<div id="menu">
     <div id="menu-left"></div>

        <a href="/doweets/index"><div id="home-btn" class="menu-item" onmouseover="RollMenu(this, event);" onmouseout="RollMenu(this, event);"><img src="/images/menu/home.jpg" /></div></a>
        <a href="/calendar/week"><div id="calendar-btn" class="menu-item" onmouseover="RollMenu(this, event);" onmouseout="RollMenu(this, event);"><img src="/images/menu/calendar.jpg" /></div></a>
        <a href="/findfriends"><div id="addfriends-btn" class="menu-item" onmouseover="RollMenu(this, event);" onmouseout="RollMenu(this, event);"><img src="/images/menu/addfriends.jpg" /></div></a>
        <div class="menu-item"><img src="/images/menu/line.jpg" /></div>

        <div id="menu-name"><%= current_user.name %></div>

        <a href="/notifications/index"><div id="notifications-btn" class="menu-item" onmouseover="RollMenu(this, event);" onmouseout="RollMenu(this, event);"><img src="/images/menu/notifications.jpg" /></div></a>
        <a href="/users/edit"><div id="settings-btn" class="menu-item" onmouseover="RollMenu(this, event);" onmouseout="RollMenu(this, event);"><img src="/images/menu/settings.jpg" /></div>
        <a href="/users/sign_out"><div id="logout-btn" class="menu-item" onmouseover="RollMenu(this, event);" onmouseout="RollMenu(this, event);"><img src="/images/menu/logout.jpg" /></div></a>

        <div id="menu-right"></div>

        <!-- Rollover states -->
        <div id="menu-rollover-left"></div>
        <div id="menu-rollover-right"></div>
</div>



   <!-- Notifications flag -->
   <a href="/notifications/index"><div id="red-flag" onmouseover="RollMenu(this, event);" onmouseout="RollMenu(this, event);">
<%= count %>

<% if count == 0 %>
<script>$("#red-flag").css("display", "none");</script>
<% end %>

</div></a>
```

at some pages of the menu it dosent working at all.
thank you all.
Nir.

Comment: Please try to pare down the problem. Delete irrelevant CSS and HTML as long as the problem remains. This will help you and us isolate your problem.

Comment: believe me i would, the problem is i dont know witch part is wrong this is why im sharing all this. sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: If I understand the problem: when you highlight a menu, a black box should appear BELOW it? Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to change?

Comment: @user827251 If you don't know which parts are relevant and which are superfluous fluff, do this: 1. Delete some code; 2. Does the problem remain? If so, repeat step 1; if not, put that code back in…and repeat step 1. Keep doing it until there's really nothing left to delete without making the problem go away (or not be visible).

Comment: Finally, never send us your ERb code when the problem is with HTML/CSS. Always copy/paste what the browser sees, not your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='#' alt='Back to the homepage'><img src='' alt='Home'><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='' alt=''><img src='' alt=''/><span>Lorem</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu { display:block; padding:0 0 0 5px; background:#ccc; }
#menu li { display:inline-block; padding:0 5px 0 0; height:20px; }
#menu li a { position:relative; }
#menu li a span { position:absolute; top:20px; }
#menu li a:link span,
#menu li a:visited span { display:none; }
#menu li a:hover span,
#menu li a:active span { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is with different elements with `position: relative` and `position: absolute`. It's hard to see exactly (especially cause I'm not sure which element the black boxes are supposed to be). However, I see you assigned elements with `position: relative` a z-index, which doesn't work. I think what's going on is that the absolutely positioned elements are pushing your little black flag down in chrome and IE, but are not in Firefox. If possible, try converting everything to `position: absolute` - it's worked for me to get around FF problems just like this.

Also, if you gave a URL I'm sure there are plenty of people who'd be happy to play with it in firebug til it's fixed.